# Maven replaces properties of resources folder

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm building a code that generates a Maven project. Its template is part of the resources folder. I want to keep the pom.xml and assembly.xml of the generated project as is. e.g.:
    ${project.build.directory}/src/main/scala/com/actimize/amp/modelExtension/

But after building the main project I get:
 C://D/...src/main/scala/resources/

How can I tell Maven to keep the values as is?

Comment: Turn off resource filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to chrylis's comment, I solve it:
Turning of resource filtering in pom.xml file.